# TypeScript Shared codebase with two output directories

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I faced a problem :/
I want the shared codebase "shared" to be in both directories. Is this possible with typescript itself or do I need some extra build-tasks? Is there a better solution?

**Important**: The "shared" folder needs to be generated in **srv** and **app**, otherwise our core system would break.

I've got following `src` directory, where client contains a client.ts, server a server.ts and shared contains a index.ts. Now I want to use shared in client.ts and server.ts.

```
src
   - client
     - client.ts
     - tsconfig.json
   - server
     - server.ts
     - tsconfig.json
   - shared
     - index.ts
     - tsconfig.json
```

If I'm compiling my TypeScript, the following output should be generated.

```
app
   - client
     - client.js
   - shared
     - index.ts
srv
   - server
     - server.js
   - shared
     - index.ts
```

Here are my configs for each directory
**client/tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2018",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outDir": "../../app",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "diagnostics": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "client.ts"
    ],
    "references": [
        { "path": "../shared"}
    ]
}
```

**server/ts.config.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2018",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outDir": "../../srv",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "diagnostics": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "server.ts"
    ],
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "../shared"
        }
    ]
}
```

**shared/tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "declaration": true, 
      "declarationMap": true,
      "composite": true,     
    },
    "include": [
      "*.*"
    ],
    "references": []
}
```

PS: If there is a better solution to solve this issue. Please let me know :)

Kind regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

You could try potentially turning the /shared folder into a separate npm package and then using `npm link` / `npm install` to join them together in each individual project? I did something similar with React and React Native using TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript compilation process will not move or append files for you. It's just creating .js files for .ts files. With only tsc, there is no way to create bundles.

You should use a bundler like webpack
Here is a link which might help: https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/

---

This being said, I think what you want to do is not correct. I assume your client is a single page application and server is a node server to serve those files?
If so, you will run your server in node environment and serve client.js.

You can bundle client.js (with webpack or other cli tools) and serve it directly from server.js. Server.js won't need shared.js or client.js to be in the same directory unless you only copy server directory to somewhere.

---

EDIT: PS: There are monorepo approaches for such use cases in big scale projects. I'd suggest to take a look at 'yarn workspaces' and 'lerna'

Comment: My node server isnt serving client files, its seperated from each other. Thats why I need this "shared" directory in both directories.

Comment: I don't understand what you exactly mean by 'need directory'. If you have this structure and if you'd only run 'node-ts server/server.ts', it'll just work. Are you separating them when you are publishing/running?

Comment: Another HTTP Server is serving the client files and our server files will be run via nodejs.

Comment: Ok, clear. You need a bundler or symlinks for sure. 
A bundler would do the trick more cleaner and error proof